# Use aspell in emacs for editing HTML pages

Tags: html, emacs, aspell, ispell

I am using the ispell-buffer command in emacs (with aspell as the backend spell checker) to check for typos in the content of HTML pages, but aspell complains at every HTML tag. Is there any way to configure it to ignore HTML tags?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `flyspell-prog-mode` works with programming modes by only looking at strings and comments.  Perhaps it can be tweaked to look only at HTML content and not tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  (setq ispell-skip-html t))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'my-web-mode-hook)
```